# Ontario HST rebate: Does a single parent of an 18 year old qualify for the maximum payment?

Tags: canada, ontario, hst, rebate

As a single parent of an 18 year old, am I still considered a single parent?

Answer (score 2):

**No, sorry.**  You would be considered a *single individual* for the purpose of the rebate.  Refer to the Ministry of Revenue's FAQ, [Who is considered to be a single individual?](https://www.rev.gov.on.ca/en/credit/sttb/faq_eligibility.html#Q19)  Excerpt:

> **You are considered to be a single
>   individual, if you are single,**
>   separated, divorced, or widowed, and
>   you are 18 years of age or older **and
>   do not live with any dependent
>   children under the age of 18.**
>   ...
>
> *[emphasis mine]*